# Assigning variable value as table column name

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

```
if request.POST['table'] == 'a':
   get_table = A_table()
   get_column = 'a'
elif request.POST['table'] == 'b':
   get_table = B_table()
   get_column = 'b'

get_table. + get_column + _column = 'some text'
```

The sample code above is just an idea which of course won't work.

How do I assign a variable value as table column name in django?

this will be used in a separate function for dynamic filtering..
a simpler example would be:

```
tablename.+'col'+name = 'test data'
```

tried using exec() and it worked according to my needs but some suggested that it is a bad way of initiating a code, any replacement for it?